# Find and replace text from excel vba in a word document

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word, find

I am trying to create multiple word documents all based on one template, currently I can open the template word doc and save it as the file name I want which gets pulled from a table in excel. What I want to do is replace the text "##Title##" in the template before I save it as a new document. This is the code I have which does not replace any text:

```
            Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(reportTemplate)
            objDoc.Content.Find.Text = "##Title##"
            objDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "##Title##"
            objDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            objDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = clients(i)
            objDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute
            objWord.Visible = True
            objDoc.SaveAs (fileName)
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do an *execute* when searching (only for replacing), and a common answer here would be :

```
With objDoc.Content.Find

.Text = "##Title##"
.Replacement.Text = clients(i)
.Forward = True
.Format = True
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne   
End With
```

The microsoft official documentation also has [good examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/finding-and-replacing-text-or-formatting)

Comment: Thank you, however it does not seem to be replacing the text? When it opens the word doc, ##Title## is still in the doc but it has been saved correctly

Comment: Never mind added in a reference to word in the tools menu which has fixed it. Thank you for your help!